# Map from coproduct of products to product of coproducts

Tags: gr.group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

Consider obvious (imagine generators as $k \times l$ dot rectangle) epimorphism $$p: \Bbb Z^k * \dots (l \text{ times}) \dots \Bbb Z^k \to F(l)^{\times k}$$ where $F(l)$ are relatively free groups in some variety; cases which are most interesting for me are all groups and nilpotent of some class $d$ — one can assume that $d=2$, but I rather wouldn't — and free products are corresponding verbal free products. I want some sensible description of $ker \, p$ and its abelianization as $F(l)^{\times k}$-module. ("Sensible" means "somewhat functorial wrt deletion and addition of rows and columns, and hopes for uniform answer for all nilpotence degrees".)

Comment: In the case of the variety of all groups, this is a surjective homomorphism between raags (right-angled artin groups) on the same generators, given by making "more generators commute". So it might be classical.

Comment: That is the reason why I'm asking this question on MO — maybe someone have done my work already, and now I'm here to reap the benefit.

Comment: I even considered naming that question "particular extensions of «RAA» groups", but then moved to current one, which may be less appropriate to attract someone who knows answer because that answer lies near busy road, but closer to what I'm feeling it is really about — for other categories of algebras my question makes sense as well.